# Standard naming conventions for development and release candidate subdomains of subdomains

Tags: php, naming-conventions, subdomain

I have subdomains for my site: clients.example.com and contractors.example.com.  Are there any standards or naming conventions for the development and release candidate areas, i.e. dev-clients.example.com and rc-clients.example.com?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be exposing your development environment, just the release candidates. I guess the term you're looking for is '[staging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_%28websites%29)'.

On a slightly unrelated note. It could be worthwhile to change your application so that it isn't dependent on a unique vhost or subdomain.

We can run all our applications from:

http://customername.domain.com/application_name/ or something similar.

This leaves the option of having a subdomain, but doesn't require it. This way you wont need to add vhosts for every application and you wont need to update your DNS.

Comment: thx for taking time out to respond, appreciate it!  My client constantly wants to see the latest updates, so without exposing the dev, how should I show them changes?

Comment: I would argue that a development environment is an environment that is extremely volatile, stuff may be broken and that's fine. If you want your customer to do reviewing and testing you'd use the staging server for that. I don't think it's reasonable for a customer to demand constant updates. Perhaps weekly or bi-weekly is more reasonable. It's also useful to have an easy way to deploy a new version of your application (to the staging server).

Comment: Got it, that makes a lot of sense.  Thanks so much for taking time out of your day to provide some insight!